# Strange awk syntax: Number with two dots?

Tags: awk

By accident I did

```
gawk 'BEGIN { print 1.2.3+4; }'
```

and received

```
1.24.3
```

I expected a syntax error because of the two dots in the number.
What happened here ?
Is that a bug in GNU awk or is it a feature ?

Same result with these versions:
`GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)` from Ubuntu 16.04 and
 `GNU Awk 4.1.0, API: 1.0 (GNU MPFR 3.1.2, GNU MP 4.3.2)` from cygwin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

```
1.2.3+4
```

gawk parses as *two numeric expressions:* `1.2` and `.3+4`.

(The second dot is *not allowed* to be a part of the first expression, so the parser consider it as the *start of another expression.*)

The second expression is the sum of `.3` and `4`, which gawk correctly evaluates, obtaining `4.3`.

Then it prints `1.2` and `4.3` (without a delimiter):

```
1.24.3
```